# What to add in this code for multiple element hover?

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

A developer gave me this code to track image hover by class in google tag manager.

```
<script>
// Tracking Top Links Hover Menus
  function trackHoverIntent(selector, time) {
    var timeoutId;
    var elements = window.document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
        var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
        var classes = targetElement.className;
        var id = targetElement.id;
        var alt = targetElement.alt;
        if (!timeoutId) {
          timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
            dataLayer.push({
              'event': 'gtm.hover',
              'gtm.element': targetElement,
              'gtm.elementClasses': classes,
              'gtm.elementId': id,
              'gtm.elementalt': alt,
              'gtm.elementHoverTime': time
            });
            timeoutId = null;
          }, time);
        }
      });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        if (timeoutId) {
          window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
          timeoutId = null;
        }
      });
    }
  } 
trackHoverIntent('img.afg-celebrate' , 1500);

  </script>
```

I have faced 2 issues here,

1. I have multiple images to track the hover. What to do, because this code only tracks one image?
2. Some images have only alt text, but no class and id. So can they be tracked by alt text? Any code?

I tried to read blogs but didnt get any solution.

Comment: change the argument like so: `trackHoverIntent('img', 1500);` and you'll track hovers on every single image, or keep adding more `trackHoverIntent('img.somesleector')` until youve got all the images you need being tracked

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. Additionally, can you tell me a way to select images by the image alt text attribute?any code?

Comment: You have to pass the right `selector` argument for your needs. If you pass img it will track ALL images, I suppose that you want to track maybe product images, so use the class they use in the HTML.

Comment: `trackHoverIntent('img[alt]', 1500);` to select all images which have an alt text attribute.

Comment: Thanks Marios and TimW for your awesome answers. Appreciate it!

Comment: Hey TimW, how can I mention specific alt or id for an image in trackHoverIntent('img[alt]', 1500)?